# StaticInjectorError during ng test

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when i run ng test my app module seems ok I have all imports in my module and in servive test i have providers [service ] i dont know why all the tests are failing below is one of the failing test any one please suggestions thank you

```
   Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[OrderService -> HttpClient]: 
              StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OrderService -> HttpClient]: 
                NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
                at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular 
            Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[OrderService -> HttpClient]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OrderService -> HttpClient]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

This is service class

```
import  { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http"; 

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

  baseUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders';

  filterUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders?start=?&end=?';

  private order: Order;
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrders(From: Date, To: Date): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '?start=' + From + '&end=' + To)
      .pipe(map(this.extractData),
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  createOrder(order: Order): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(order), {headers: this.headers})
      .pipe(map(this.extractData),
        catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I app module.ts i have

```
imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
      providers: [OrderService,TruckService],
export class AppModule {
   constructor(router: Router) {
     console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
    }
 }
```

This is the test

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ TruckService ]
    });
  });

  afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (httpClient: HttpTestingController) => {
    httpClient.verify();
  }));


  it(`should create`, async(inject([TruckService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: TruckService, httpClient: HttpTestingController) => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    })));
```

Comment: This information may be of some help: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: no it doesnt help i am doing it as they have written but it doesnt work

Comment: If you are doing it as written, why do I not see you using `HttpClientTestingModule` in your spec?

Comment: let httpClient: HttpClient; this is line in the doc should be replaced with my service i think ?

Comment: so i did   orderService = TestBed.get(OrderService);

Comment: since orderservice in an injectable service that gets resource frombackend

Comment: i have updated my test look and see if its done right thank you

Comment: Looks like it is getting there. [Here](https://github.com/rdrrichards/QIQO.Business.Accounts.Client/blob/1151aeab3d067e138b56138e0de546fa98a747c5/src/app/services/account.service.spec.ts) is a spec I wrote that may help you, too. Do your tests run now?

Comment: yes i ran the test  it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
    const testData: Data = {name: 'Test Data'};

    // Make an HTTP GET request
    httpClient.get<Data>('http://localhost:8088/trucks')
      .subscribe(data =>
        // When observable resolves, result should match test data
        expect(data).toEqual(testData)
      );  then i got this Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test

Comment: Interesting. I don't see where in your service that you are using a Promise. Is this a new issue? A different spec?

Comment: no its the same so i dont understand why it showed that , i will post my new solution right now , inspired by your link

Comment: let me test first

Comment: i edited my answer with the help of you link so it passes , i am new to angular can you post it as solution now so i like it and may be you explain a bit what i was doing wrong, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test services that use the HttpClient, you are going to have to include the testing module and controller that come from Angular for this.

This includes `HttpClientTestingModule` for backend configuration, and `HttpTestingController` for mocking and flushing of requests.

Here is something that could work for you:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TruckService } from './truck.service';

describe('TruckService', () => {

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    providers: [ TruckService ]
    });
});

afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (httpClient: HttpTestingController) => {
    httpClient.verify();
}));

it(`should create`, async(inject([TruckService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: TruckService, httpClient: HttpTestingController) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
})));
});
```

For details on testing HTTP requests in the Angular HttpClient, go [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests). Here are API details on [`HttpClientTestingModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule), and [`HttpTestingController`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController).

Comment: this way of writing test is what jasmine ? or do i have a wrong assumption? @R. Richards